# Rails Bootstrap Datatables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable, twitter-bootstrap

I am successfully using the  jquery-datatables-rails gem with twitter bootstrap.  Using bootstraps requires using:

```
  sPaginationType: "bootstrap"
```

in the datatable jquery function.  All is good.

By default the bootstrap pagination looks like this:

```
  <- previous  1  2  3  4  5  next ->
```

Is there a way to limit the number of pages created by the bootstrap pagination? For instance, so it looks like this?:

```
  <- previous  1  2  3 next ->
```

Comment: jQuery has this setting "jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination.iFullNumbersShowPages = 3;".  But, that doesnt affect the bootstrap pagination.

Comment: maybe this will help http://cssdeck.com/labs/twitter-bootstrap-pagination-and-pager

Comment: it's not twitter bootstrap who decides how many pages will be listed here. it must be done by your other codes!

Comment: True, but jquery.dataTables.bootstrap creates the pagination.  So, setting "iFullNumbersShowPages" (like I showed above) won't work because you cant call sPaginationType: "full_numbers", on the datatable...you must call sPaginationType: "bootstrap".  Therefor, for what I can tell, you cant override the pagination using the straight datatable override...  Im probably wrong...

Comment: I tried "aLengthMenu": [ [1, 2, -1], [1, 2, "All"] ] ... but that didn't change anything.  Anyone know how to limit the pages in pagination using the bootstrap data tables gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of displayed pages is hardcoded in sample code given by dataTables (and in the jquery-datatables-rails gem).

I submitted [a pull-request](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails/pull/37) to use the same behavior as "full_numbers" pagination.

When this pull-request will be merged, you will just have to initialize your datatables like that:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination.iFullNumbersShowPages = 3;
$('#my-table').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "bScrollCollapse": true
});
```

Comment: Sweet!  I adjusted CSS to make things fit a bit better...but, will definitely follow that request. Thanks!

Comment: The PR has been merged. Enjoy!